# Create a Form to Edit Item in a Custom List View

Tags: infopath, custom-form, list-form, edit-form

I'm trying to create a form that allows a user to edit items they see in a Custom List View. I know about New/Display/Edit Forms that are associated with a Custom List. I believe this is probably close to the solution I am looking for.

I created an Edit Form using InfoPath and it showed up as `editifs.aspx` in my Cutom List page on SharePoint Designer (based on what I learned from [this Microsoft support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-list-forms-using-infopath-2010-in-sharepoint-designer-f86cf514-9a11-4613-a479-12a1a0132d22)). Now, I can create a link to this new Edit Form in the links column on my SharePoint Website.

But this is not the functionality I am looking for. **I want the Edit Form to open when I click on an item in the Custom List.** *And I want this to happen only from one of the Views of the Custom List.* Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much there. Just in custom view remove the Title (linked to item) column and replace it with the link column you crated. This way in normal view the standard form will open and in the custom view your edit form.